# How to split comma separated strings in a column into different columns if they're not of same length using python or pandas in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, jupyter-notebook

I am learning python and working on a sample Kaggle dataset and trying to split comma-separated values in a column into different columns using python or pandas in jupyter notebook.

For instance :

**column_A**

Garbage: Tissues, Organics: Milk, Recycle: Cardboards

Garbage: Paper Towels, Organics: Eggs, Recycle: Glass, Junk: Feces

Garbage: cups, Recycle: Plastic bottles

I want to split these into different columns based on commas, like below:

| Garbage | Organics | Recycle | Junk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tissues | Milk | Cardboards | Null |
| Paper Towels | Eggs | Glass | Feces |
| Cups | Null | Plastic bottles | Null |

I've tried using Lambda functions but it only worked if there is same length of comma separated strings but not for unequal length and displaying an index error "list index out of range". The code I've used is below:

```
list_of_dicts = [{x1.split(':')[0].strip():x1.split(':')[1].strip() for x1 in x.split(',')} for x in Df1['column_name']]
Df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list_of_dicts)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regular expression pattern to find all the matching key-value pairs from each row of `column_A` , then `map` the list of pairs from each row to dictionary in order to create records then construct a dataframe from these records

```
pd.DataFrame(map(dict, df['column_A'].str.findall(r'\s*([^:,]+):\s*([^,]+)')))
```

See the online [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9pFjLg/1)

```
        Garbage Organics          Recycle   Junk
0       Tissues     Milk       Cardboards    NaN
1  Paper Towels     Eggs            Glass  Feces
2          cups      NaN  Plastic bottles    NaN
```

---

Here is an alternate approach in case you don't want to use regular expression patterns

```
df['column_A'].str.split(', ').explode()\
              .str.split(': ', expand=True)\
              .set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked Flawlessly. Can you pls able to explain the expression that you've used in str.findall ? It's only used to match the pattern, right?

Comment: @TheWeightedTooth Correct. It is a regular expression pattern which is used to find the occurrences of key-val pairs. For example considering third row as the input the pattern will produce the following output `[(Garbage, cups), (Recycle, plastic bottles)]`